# When building an iPhone App in Xcode 4.x why does the build fail with "clang failed with exit code 254"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, linker-errors, clang

I seen clang fail with exit code 1 before and I was able to track that down to a problem with incorrect frameworks or libraries that I had included in the project but I have no idea what this error means.

My project is very simple. It is a basic iPhone app and I have included a few pre-built static libraries that I plan on using, specifically: `libetpan.a`, `libsasl2.a` and `libssl.a`. I have code in my project that calls a couple of functions in libetpan.a and that's all the app does.

Compilation seems to go smoothly until I get that lone linker error with no help as to what is actually causing it.

Comment: Can you show us the full output from the linker stage please?

Comment: Is it the problem when you try build app on device or simulator? Also can you post complete linker error.

Comment: I'm really confused now. Suddenly this error just went away. I don't think I changed any build settings or anything, and I had done a clean and build and restarted Xcode several times. I'll see if I have this problem again. If not, I will probably delete this question.